# Problem loading an array initialized in another script on webpage

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This seems like a ridiculously easy thing, but I still haven't been able to figure it out.
I'm using a script to receive and structure some data from a web API. It puts it all in an array, and then another script, which should load a bit later, uses those data to draw a chart with Highcharts.

My data-fetching script looks like this:

```
var dataSeries = [];

fetch('https://eu-west-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-stitch.com/api/client/v2.0/app/semapres-charts-dsioa/service/get-chart-data/incoming_webhook/get-day?secret=secret').then(
    function(response){
        return response.json();
    }
).then(function(jsonData){
    for (let i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++) {
        dataSeries.push([jsonData[i][0].$date.$numberLong, jsonData[i][1].$numberDouble]);
    }
});
```

My Highchart script looks like this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
        let dataSeriesTest = [[1555318393000, 103.28],[1555318423000, 104.28]];
        var myChart = Highcharts.chart('highchart-container', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Time'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Pressure (kPa)'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Sensor0',
                data: dataSeries
            }]
        });
});
```

And while my html page is very long, it has this at the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sematek Pontongtrykk</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/bundles/4.3.1/stitch.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
  <script src="data-fetch.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="highcharter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

And this is close to the bottom of the page:

```
  <div id="highchart-container" width="100%" height="400"></div>
```

I get the chart to draw, it looks all right with my test data, but when debugging I get that my Array dataSeries has a length of 0, inside the Highcharts script. It also seems to debug that script before my data fetcher script, despite using the jQuery load method. 
I'm sure that my data fetcher script is working and making an array out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who has the same problem, I found a solution, which was continuing the promise chain in order to pass the data to the Highcharts bit.

This is the result of both scripts:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    let dataSeries = [];
    fetch('https://eu-west-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-stitch.com/api/client/v2.0/app/semapres-charts-dsioa/service/get-chart-data/incoming_webhook/get-day?secret=secret').then(
        function (response) {
            return response.json();
        }
    ).then(function (jsonData) {
        for (let i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        let time = jsonData[i][0].$date.$numberLong;
        let val = jsonData[i][1].$numberDouble
            dataSeries.push([parseInt(time),parseFloat(val)]);
        }
        return dataSeries;
    }).then(function (dataSeries) {
        let myChart = Highcharts.chart('highchart-container', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Time'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Pressure (kPa)'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Sensor0',
                data: dataSeries
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should load the data in the same script in which you are creating a chart:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var dataSeries = [];

    fetch('https://eu-west-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-stitch.com/api/client/v2.0/app/semapres-charts-dsioa/service/get-chart-data/incoming_webhook/get-day?secret=secret').then(
        function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }
    ).then(function(jsonData) {
        for (let i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
            dataSeries.push([jsonData[i][0].$date.$numberLong, jsonData[i][1].$numberDouble]);
        }

        createChart();
    });

    function createChart() {
        var myChart = Highcharts.chart('highchart-container', {
            ...
        });
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hdjqgebt/

Alternatively, you can add the `app.js` script after the data is loaded:

```
var dataSeries = [];

fetch(...).then(function(jsonData) {
    for (let i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        ...
    }

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "app.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is the asynchronous behavior.

I assume that your `app.js` contains the array initializing and fetching which means it will start executing before `highcharter.js` but your array won't be populated right away since the fetching takes time.

That is why continuing the promise chain will solve your problem.

```
$(window).load(() => {
  fetch('...')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data.map(item => [parseInt(item[0].$data.$numberLong), parseFloat(item[1].$numberDouble)]))
    .then(doTheMagicWithHighcharter);
})
```

Note that you don't need to initialize the array `dataSeries` because you are passing it via the chain.